# Webdriver reference is getting mixed with each other in parallel execution when we used ThreadLocal in Selenium C# with Nunit

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit

Created a ThreadLocal instance with type of IWebDriver,

Base class we have extended in all test classes and driver.value is pass to all page classes while creating instance of page class in test classes.

below is my sample code snippet,

```
public class BaseClass{
public ThreadLocal<IWebDriver?> driver = new ThreadLocal<IWebDriver?>();
[SetUp]
public void InitializeDriver()
{
 driver.value = new ChromeDriver();
}
}
```

```
[TestFixture]
[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.All)]
public void TestClass : BaseClass{
[SetUp]
public void RunBeforeEachTestcase()
{
 PageClass page = new PageClass(driver.value); //page class represent POM
}

[Test]
public void Testcase1()
{
 page.EnterUserName();
}

[Test]
public void Testcase2()
{
 page.EnterUserName();
}
}
```

Comment: You haven't really explained the problem. What do you expect this code to do and what does it do instead? Please edit the question to clarify.